# ElasticSearch won't run

Tags: java, elasticsearch, virtualbox

I am facing with problem when try to start elasticsearch. Problem has started when I migrate my project to another laptop. WHen I start elastic search for the first time my GitBash get freezed, and when I again try to run elastic I get this error:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ starts elasticsearch

Option                Description
------                -----------
-E <KeyValuePair>     Configure a setting
-V, --version         Prints elasticsearch version information and exits
-d, --daemonize       Starts Elasticsearch in the background
-h, --help            show help
-p, --pidfile <Path>  Creates a pid file in the specified path on start
-q, --quiet           Turns off standard ouput/error streams logging in console
-s, --silent          show minimal output
-v, --verbose         show verbose output
ERROR: D is not a recognized option
```

I am using Windows 10. Could someone help me?

Comment: have installed as service or have setup folder?

Comment: I have setup folder...but other colleges in my team don't have problems just me, so I suppose that with the file is everything okay..

Comment: i see u try to start elasticsearch, may i know where you found the  script to start elasticsearch like that?

Comment: I found it in my project in vagrant file.

Comment: The screen shot u have attached.. is shows it ran in ubuntu... cound you post the win 10 screen..

Comment: Well I am starting elastic on virtual machine(Ubuntu)

Comment: is there a starts.sh file in folder?

Comment: Yes, of course...Could we go to chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145860/discussion-between-blackpop-and-atenica).